# Doctrine many to many property as return value

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-orm, many-to-many

I have a two entities Restaurant and Cuisine and the Restaurant has a many-to-many relationship with Cuisine named, funnily enough, cuisines.

So if I have two restaurants (rest1, rest2) and two cuisines (indian, chinese), and both restaurants have only indian

```
rest1  indian
rest2  indian
```

I would like to perform a DQL query, via the query builder, that returns a list of cuisines along with a count of how many restaurants are assigned the cuisine. So, theoretically something like this.

```
$qb->select('rc AS cuisine, COUNT(r) AS restaurantCount')
   ->from('Restaurant', 'r')
   ->join('r.cuisines', 'rc')
   ->addGroupBy('rc');
```

So, as a result, I would like

```
cuisine: indian restaurantCount: 2
```

I know that this will give an error as the main entity needs to be returned.

I also know that this is possible by creating and using the inverse of the many-to-many, but I'm trying to avoid giving the cuisine a restaurants property to avoid the complexity of a bidirectional relationship.

Is it possible to get the desired result by using the Restaurant as the main selecting table?

Answer (score 0):

In a clean OOP way, without using bidirectional relationship, I don't think it is possible.
It doesn't make a lot of sense, you are selection restaurants, but returning something else.

However you can always use raw SQL for things like this.
IMHO a lot faster and cleaner solution than forcing a bidirectional relationship just for this.